# how to display a message at certain times of the day in ios app

Tags: ios, swift

I need my app to display messages for the user at particular times of the day if the app is running. How can I reference the current time of a user's device? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which classes have you looked at? What went wrong?

Comment: I just need a general advice. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the NSDate class to get the time of the day. For example:

```
let date = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute, fromDate: date)
let hour = components.hour
let minutes = components.minute
```